# ¿Cómo puedo animar una imagen para que se voltee cada minuto?

Tags: c#, imagen, wpf, rectangle, animación

Tengo un software en cuya esquina inferior izquierda aparece su logotipo, pero quisiera que cada 60 segundos el logo se voltee y luego vuelva a su posición.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen está dentro de un control `Rectangle` y la idea es que -como dije- cada 60 segundos se voltee en una animación que no dure más de 1 segundo y pasado 1 segundos más se voltee a la inversa para quedar en su posición original, ya tengo experiencia con otras animaciones pero esto no lo hice nunca.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que intentaste hasta ahora.

Comment: En realidad no hay efectos 3d en WFP, lo mas similar sería ver que se puede conseguir con los efectos y animación 2d que dispone

Comment: Lo mas facil seria copiar esa imagen en el paint darle la vuelta y guardarla con otro normbre, y luego con un Timer poner una imagen o la otra en funcion de un booleano que cambia con cada Tick

Answer (score 0):

No existen las animaciones 3D en WPF, una opción sería generar un gif con cualquier programa de edición para obtener la animación que quieres.
De esta forma tendrías la imagen fija y con un timer podrías ocultar y mostrar tanto el gif como la imagen para crear el efecto visual.

Comment: Bienvenido! gracias por responder. como veras, es una pregunta muy vieja, y puede que nadie siga esta respuesta. Te recomiendo leer el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Gracias por participar!